# Need to setup Azure WebApp with Loadbalancer and fault tollerance

Tags: load-balancing, azure-web-app-service, fault-tolerance, azure-traffic-manager, internal-load-balancer

I have a website which is created using ASP.Net, C#, Azure SQL and it is hosted on Azure Webapp.

I have a requirement where I need to setup Loadbalancer for website with fault tolerance.

I have set up a Traffice manager where there are two replicas of my site as end points. (mywebsitea.azure.com, mywebsiteb.azure.com)

It is using Performance algorithm of internal Azure load balancer, one site is hosted in asia region and another is hosted at west europe region.
This all works good. (mywebsite.trafficmanager.com)

Now I also wish to set up a fault tolerance mechanism. Can we configure both of load balancer and fault tolerance using traffic manager?

or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be mixing terminology: you say "It is using Performance algorithm of internal Azure load balancer".  However, 'Performance' is a mode of Azure Traffic Manager, not Azure load balancer.

To answer your question: **all** Traffic Manager traffic-routing methods (including 'Performance') include health checks and endpoint failover.

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani

Program Manager

Azure Networking - DNS and Traffic Manager